# How can I remove disabled effect from Radio Button?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'd like to have a Radio Button whose IsEnable property doesn't make any change in its visual appearance. However, the Radio Button shouldn't allow user to do anything when its IsEnable property is False.

I just want want to have a Radio Button which looks same irrespective of its IsEnable property. Apart from Visual appearance everything else should work as it is.

You may find it as a strangest requirement. But I want to achieve this. I'm using Radio Buttons as List Box items in List Box. Everything works good, but the problem occurs when user do Ctrl Mouse Left Click on checked Radio button. That's where everything fails.

Please help me.

Comment: Ashwin its very confusing..Make it clear please :)

Comment: Hi Sunil, We know that whenever we set Radio Button's IsEnable property to False, it's Foregrround, Background, Circle Foreground and Background changes. I just don't want this to happen whenever I set IsEnable to False. I want my Radio Button to look as good as Enabled even if I set it's IsEnabled property to False. Hope I'm clear this time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to extract the ControlTemplate of a RadioButton and then remove the style for Disable trigger. Below is an example of a standard template for a RadioButton. Just comment out the trigger IsEnable = False

```
<Style x:Key="RadioButtonStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#F4F4F4"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource CheckBoxStroke}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}">
                        <BulletDecorator Background="Transparent">
                            <BulletDecorator.Bullet>
                                <Themes:BulletChrome BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" IsChecked="{TemplateBinding IsChecked}" IsRound="true" RenderMouseOver="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}" RenderPressed="{TemplateBinding IsPressed}"/>
                            </BulletDecorator.Bullet>
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                        </BulletDecorator>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="HasContent" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource CheckRadioFocusVisual}"/>
                                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="4,0,0,0"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

Comment: Thanks Krishna for taking time and answering my question!

Comment: Thanks Krishna for taking time and answering my question! However even after commenting out IsEnabled trigger I can easily see the difference. No difference observed after commenting out.

Comment: What difference are you noticing? Can you post a screenshot of what you want it to look like and what it is looking like at the moment?

Comment: A silly question really, did you really use the style 'RadioButtonStyle1' on your RadioButton? as <RadioButton Style="{StaticResource RadioButtonStyle1}" >

Comment: Following is the code snippet of the Simple Window. Uncomment code of Style to test my claim.

Comment: I simple added the style you mentioned in <Window.Resources> and removed the Key name so that by default it is applicable to every Radio Button. After that I commented the IsEnabled Trigger. Though I wasn't seeing any difference in the Enabled and Disabled Radio Button, the circle in both the Radio Buttons appears as disabled and that won't be accepted. I want disabled Radio Buttons to appear as same as Enabled Radio Buttons (the way they appear normally).

Comment: Ok. I think I get you now, the circle will look disabled as there will be a separate style for that. Let me see what I can do

Answer (score 0):

Ashwin,

Its Very simple

Just follow the steps.

1. Right Click on the RadioButton, Edit Template and Edit a Copy
2. Then go to the Style created and comment out the code in storyboard of Disabled Visual state as shown in this image "https://i.stack.imgur.com/3TNoR.png"
3. Then it must look same for both states.
   Take a look at the result "https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCL47.png"

Hope it solved your purpose.
Thanks,